# Android data transfer from activity to another activity's tablayout fragment

Tags: android, design-patterns, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

OneActivity -> TabLayout - > FragmentA, FragmentB, FragmentC

TwoActivity -> some clickable widgets

From **FragmentA** I will go to **TwoActivity** ang again from **TwoActivity** to another instance of **TwoActivity** and again from **TwoActivity** to another instance of **TwoActivity**   and if some action happens in these **TwoActivity** I want to have that action value in **FragmentC** of **OneActivity** if user navigate to **FragmentC**.

I tried eventbus but not found solution for it.
I want to know the best design pattern for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `startActivityForResult` and `override` the method `onActivityResult` in the `OneActivity` to handle the result returned from `TwoActivity` and forward the result to `FragmentC` in your own method.
Another way you can use `Observers` and `Observable` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html)

Comment: dont you think I know that solution ?

Comment: why you guys just post solutions for jsut points.This is senior level programmer question.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1.) call startActivityForResult to navigate to TwoActivity.

2.) Override the onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) into the OneActivity.

3.) and call setResult into TwoActivity while finishing it.

4.) and in onActivityResult proceed to whatever fragment you interested with tabs.

Comment: dont you think I know that solution ?

Comment: why you guys just post solutions for jsut points.This is senior level programmer question.